# videoView seekTo not working after video edited using ffmpeg library - android

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, android-videoview

I am using videoView to play video. And on a button click I want video to seekTo some specific position.
This is the code i am using

```
mVideoPlayer.seekTo(specificMills);
```

This is working perfectly fine when I am using this for video made by default camera application.
But when I edit the video using FFMPEG and then use the same code. It dont works :(

I played the same video in default video player but it reacts same.
Video starts from the beginning, as if it have a single starting frame. Wherever you seekTo it starts over.

This is FFMPEG command I am using

```
       String[] ffmpegCommandImages = {
                    "path/to/ffmpeg",
                    "-i", videoPath,
                    "-b:v", "1000k",
                    "-vf", "scale=-2:576",
                    "-vcodec", "libx264",  
                    "-c:a", "aac", 
                    "-strict", "-2",
                    "-b:a", "128k",
                    "-threads", "5", 
                    "-preset", "ultrafast",
                    to };
```

Comment: include the ffmpeg command you are using!

Comment: @Salmaan found any solution for the above trouble? Please let me know the solution if any.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra Yes! the problem was with the -vcodec, libx264 video isnt seekable. I used mpeg4 codec and it worked like a charm.